# Export two or more devices to event hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I have two devices to export from iot central to event hub.

I would like to know how could I export two devices on the same export.
Follow my devices bellow:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: In azure portal (or) using any coding langue

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter in the *Data export*, see the following screen snippet for your devices:

[image]

In the case of more complex filtering, conditions, etc., can be used a *Data transformation*